# Allow special characters to be rendered or compiled in scss/css with ReactJS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, character-encoding

I'm having a difficulty on including special characters in my CSS preprocessor. This is the code:

```
.xyz{
   &:before{
      content: '佥佬佧佼';
      some: properties;
   }
}
```

This runs smoothly in plain HTML.  But on my ReactJS Project, the output in my DOM is this:

```
.xyz:before{
   content: '\3A3\255C\D1\3A3\255C\BC\3A3\255C\BA\3A3\255C\255D';
}
```

Then the content has ASCII code output.
I am not sure where to put or set the character encoding.  I'm using VSC with UTF-8 encoding. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got what I was looking for.

On top of the page, write:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
```

Now everything is fine.